# Adding the values dynamically in the Listbox and then trying to get the value on the submit button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am adding the values in the listbox dynamically but when I click on submit I dont see those values in the list box.
Can someone please help me with this?

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCompanyNames, new SelectList(Model.matterFiling.SelectedCompanyList, "Value", "Text"))


function SuccessCompanyPopUp(data) {
    if (data.success == true) {
        $.each(data.objCompanyList, function (i, company) {
            $('#SelectedCompanyNames').
                append($("<option></option>").
                attr("value", company.CompanyID).
                text(company.CompanyName));
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the AJAX call to repopulate the listbox, including the controller action that populates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried multiple things like adding the hiddenfor but that didnt work. 
Then I am just selecting the values of the listbox using the below code.

But please let me know if there is any other way of getting all the values which are added dynamically to the listbox back in the submit action.

```
 if (data.success == true) {
        $.each(data.objCompanyList, function (i, company) {               
            $("#SelectedCompanyNames").append(
                $('<option></option>').val(company.CompanyID).html(company.CompanyName)).attr("selected", true);
            var a = "select option[value=" + company.CompanyID + "]";
            $(a).attr("selected", true);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try with below option:

```
var option = new Option(text, value); $('#select').append($(option));
```

Comment: Thanks for replying I have fixed the above problem. using below code